# How to get live Dom with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

After loading my page, there is a lot of html code added by some scripts.

Now, i'm trying to edit this added html, for example, there is this div `<div id="detail"><span>some content</span></div>` added after loading the page.
When i try in my JS code to get it's html : `alert($("#detail").html());` i always obtain an "undefined" message !

Is there a way to get the live html ? the html that i see with Google Chrome inspector ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: you might try console.log instead of alert

Comment: how are you adding html to the page?

Comment: `alert($("#detail").html());` will return the live HTML. But if it is called before AJAX call then it can't alert future HTML , so make sure it is called after AJAX call and for our help you have to show some more code

Comment: Ok is there a way to tell jQuery to wait for the ajax calls to end ? cause i use a library that makes some ajax calls, and after i call this library, i added my alert, so i imagine when the alert is executed, the ajax calls didn't end yet :/

Comment: Ok i found this http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/ and it solved the problem, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found this http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/

When i tried this code :

```
$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
  alert($("#detail").html());
});
```

ajaxStop is called when all the ajax calls end

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your jquery code in `document.ready`. If you are getting html data with ajax, you can set an event listener for AJAX completion - [ajaxStop](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   alert($("#detail").html());
}
```